# MacBook Pro won't start up on Mondays

Tags: macos, startup, power-management

**EDIT:  Solved it... resetting the NVRAM did the trick.**

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina. It's set in the energy settings to shut down in the evenings, and boot/wake on weekday mornings.

For easily a year, it worked perfectly, as you would expect, on every weekday. But for months now, it simply refuses to boot up on Mondays.

Only Monday morning exhibits this issue. It will always boot up as expected Tuesday to Friday.

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I will now await the first comment about my machine having "a case of the Mondays…"

EDIT: As requested, screenshots of settings...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it trying to tell you something.

Comment: what is your time zone setting

Comment: @Ruskes I'm in Pacific time but my computer is set to automatic timezone selection.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yeah I'll try the NVRAM and SMC I guess.  In all my years using macs, I don't think I've ever seen those two things fix anything, but what the heck.  May as well give it a shot.

Comment: I would say it is confused about your time zone, and thinks it is not Monday morning. Check your setting carefully, for dates and times. I do not like the automatic time zone setting, i use manual. The automatic needs a message from apple server to know where it is.

Comment: Totally get where you are coming from @Ruskes, however if it was shifted by one day, then it would be waking up on Saturdays (thinking it was Friday), and it does not do that.  Still, it's one more thing to test.

Comment: Nope, I did not say it is shifted, it needs info from apple server to update, something might be wrong with yours, **so just switch to manual time zone to test**.

Comment: Literally the case of the Mondays

Comment: Ahhhh there it is LOL

Comment: If I solve it I will.  In case it was confusing, my remark about "there it is" was in response to the "case of the mondays" comment which I was entirely expecting.  =)

Comment: @Ruskes No change at all, mac did not boot up this morning and I had to do it manually.  Happy Monday to me!

Comment: Could you publish the screen shot of your settings

Comment: Done, in OP....

Comment: @JVC does your macbook happen to be unplugged on Monday mornings? Load settings on Monday mornings around 4:30 am? A timer or smart plug on the power adapter?

Comment: Nope, never.  It's just plugged into the wall almost 24/7.  Also remember, this worked fine for years, until this strange Monday behavior started out of nowhere.

Comment: @JVC you are 100% sure your electricity company is turning off your electricity in the early mornings? Ive heard reports of it recently in California (Im in Georgia, US, so Im not rlly sure).

Comment: LOL yes, absolutely positively certain.  I'm even already awake sometimes at 4:30 so I'm sitting here doing things on my Windows PC when the clocks strikes 4:30.  Plus planned CA rolling power outages only happen during peak usage times.  ;)

Comment: Thank you for the photos. Why is your Shut down only on workdays, why not Every day ? You have the last shut down on Friday. Since there was no shutdown on Sunday, it will not wake up on Monday

Comment: I generally shut it down manually myself on Sunday nights.  But regardless, if it was still powered on come Monday morning, then I wouldn't have to manually power it up (I have it set to make the standard startup chime) in the morning at 5-6am.  It is absolutely, positively, completely powered OFF on Monday morning, and does not power up until I hit a button to boot it up.

Comment: FYI all, resetting the NVRAM appears to have done the trick.  Booted up this morning on schedule as expected.

Comment: TBH, I wouldn't bother shutting it down every night and starting it up again. Just close the lid. These things are designed to keep running.

Comment: I find that when I leave it running for long periods of time, it gets unstable.  This has always been the case with my various computers both Windows and Mac, going back decades.  Letting it shut down every night means when I arrive in the morning, everything is pristine and works flawlessly.  If I could put it to sleep rather than shutting down, at a specified time rather than after a period of idle, I would consider doing that.  I'm sure I could script it but I can't be bothered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the NVRAM (or "Zapping the PRAM" if you're old-sk00l like me) solved this issue, the machine is now eager to work on Mondays again.